# Find ids which is not connected to objects in parse.com database

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can i retrieve ids, which is not connected to real objects in parse.com database? (it is needed for delete entity synchronization)
By example an application has such array of data ids:
`String[] ids = new String[]{"id1", "id2", "id3", "id4}`.
Parse.com database has these objects :

```
{
   objectId = "id1"
   ...
}

{
   objectId = "id3"
   ...
}
```

So request have to return `{ "id2", "id4" }` array or sth similar response to represent such data, so i'll be able to delete entities, which was deleted on server. Is it possible with android sdk or should i use cloud code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it with parse.com cloud code. In my example i search for corresponding "Card" entities in parse cloud. My android app sends existed card ids in 'currentCardsIdsArray' parameter

```
Parse.Cloud.define("findDeletedCards", function(request, response) {
    var Card = Parse.Object.extend("Card");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Card);
    findDeletedEntities(query, request, response);
});

function findDeletedEntities(query, request, response){
    query.containedIn("objectId", request.params.currentCardsIdsArray);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        var _ = require("underscore");
        var foundedIds = _.map(results, function(item) {
            var id = item.id;
            return id;
        });

        var deletedIdsArray = request.params.currentCardsIdsArray.filter( function( el ) {
            return foundedIds.indexOf(el) < 0;
        } );

        response.success(deletedIdsArray);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("search deleted items failed");
    });
}
```

How it looks in application:

```
@WorkerThread
public List<String> findDeletedCards(List<String> ids) throws ParseException {
    Map<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramsMap.put("currentCardsIdsArray", ids);
    return ParseCloud.callFunction("findDeletedCards", paramsMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse is based on objects, not on id's. You should read the guide, which will help you A LOT understanding the structure model of Parse. And it is a great advantage to work with Android Studio. Just tell me what you want to retrieve: Do you need a single String, or an Array or something else?

Comment: I don't understand you well. Each parse object has own id. Programmer could check some field of that object if is it objectId, createdAt, updatedAt or any other custom, so no problem with that. But it is clear only for simple cases, not for my. I could retrieve an array of objects, which match sended array of ids. But i need to make check, which objects are not contained in parse database, but only in app (deleted on server)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to filter your objects, as I see from your question. If so, then here's the answer. In your query, you can do it like that:

```
   query.whereEqualTo("ColumnName","Value");
```

That could also help you: www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/